# PHP Remove " In GET

Tags: php, get

I simply need a GET Variable that doesn't have any " marks. ' marks are okay, but " aren't. What do I need to do to fix that? And no, changing the " marks to ' do not work. I must do this because the GET is a URL link, so the URL link must be within two " quotes. If a " mark is within those lines, it will cause the link to stop short.

```
' . $_GET["test"] . '
```

My Code

```
<?php
$user = str_replace($_GET["user"], "\"", "'");
$user = "" . $user . "";
?>

<iframe src="https://domain.tld/?user=' . $user . '&password=' . $_GET['password'] . '&version=99" height="30" width="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: There is nothing here that needs fixing. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, it can't have the " mark...

Comment: You already wrote that. Try another way. *What* is it can't have *quotes*? *Why*?

Comment: Because it is in a URL link, so the URL link must be within two " quotes. If a " mark is within those lines, it will cause the link to stop short.

Comment: Although I've answered your question, you've not worded it very descriptively. Please consider adding more detail in the future.

Comment: Then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: You have answered his question, but your answer is still not 100% correct. Exactly because there was not enough information to determine the correct answer.

Comment: Quite right, I have still answered the question "How do I remove " marks from a GET variable"

Comment: You reposted the question under a different username and said that we did not answer it... This is NOT acceptable behavior under SO rules and etiquette.. Needless to say I have expanded my answer to be a full solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply fetch the $_GET[''] variable and use a find and replace to replace all the "

Example:

```
$myVar = str_replace($_GET["myVar"], "\"", "'");
$myStringWithVar = "" . $myVar . "";
```

Full example:

```
<iframe src="https://domain.tld/?user=<?php echo
str_replace($_GET["myVar"], "\"", "'");  ?>&password=' .
$_GET['password'] . '&version=99" height="30" width="500"></iframe>
```

Please do not ask the same question again later on under a different username (as you have done)

Comment: And how exactly do I do that?

Comment: $user = str_replace($_GET["user"], "\"", "'");
$user = "" . $user . "";

Comment: Yes, you would use that... You asked how to fix the variable in that little itty bit of code you gave us, and this is my interpretation of what you were asking.

Comment: And this to display it? ' . $user . '

Comment: To display it you will want to type echo $myVar.

Comment: Still not working. I have <?php echo $user ?> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $user is not a variable... Please post more code, I can't see what you're doing.

Comment: I added the code involving the GET Variable.

Comment: Christian, tutoring is not a good use of time for that user. (Lots of deleted questions, banned accounts, more trivial inquiries to come the more you feed a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem).)

Comment: Is there a better place for blood? Im hungry.

Comment: I like to help @mario Also you can't reference PHp things from html